# Time offset in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My server default timezone is +0400 (Moscow). All instance recording to DB in UTC format. IE: it user create item at 04-00 this is recorded as 00-00. When I'm trying to get

```
Item.last
```

I see the UTC raw time. When I'm asking

```
Item.last.created_at
```

I've get +0400 time. BUT! When I'm using std time functions like

```
Item.where('created_at > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

it is making sql query

```
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE (items.created_at > '2012-11-30 00:00:00')
```

instead of

```
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE (items.created_at > '2012-11-29 20:00:00')
```

So i'm losing 4 hours. The little crunch is using in_time_zone:

```
Time.now.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone(-4)
```

But I's not a jedi way :D Any ideas?

Comment: Out of interest, how are you "recording to DB in UTC format"? Is that being handled automatically, or do you have to do that explicitly too?

Comment: @JonSkeet Rails (actually its component ActiveRecord) handles this automatically.

Comment: Okay. And what happens if you search for just values after `Time.now`? Does that *also* take off four hours (consistent with insert) or not (consistent with your queries above)? I wonder whether it's being "clever" and deciding that if you're looking for something from midnight, that you mean midnight UTC instead of local time...

Comment: Time.now returning +4 hours 'cause in app.rb my default time zone is 'moscow'. The problem in beginning_of_day - it not using default time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've solved it:

```
Time.now.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('UTC')
 => Thu, 29 Nov 2012 20:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

So this is relation **what time in Moscow when day beginnings in UTC timezone** :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope your users have some settings related to their time zones in their profiles. In this case you can do the following:

```
Time.use_zone(zone_of_current_user) do # like 'America/New_York'
  @products = Product.where('created_at > ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
end
```

This way you'll set the zone for the block.

**Note the using of `zone` method of `Time`.**

Comment: I think no. For a pure code it's good idea. But, i need it in scope

Comment: @AlexanderBochkarev You can call `use_zone` in an `around_filter` (`ApplicationController` seems to be a good place for it). This way any your action will be run in the user's time zone.